# How to modify the query that is used when autoloading related entities?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Assume there's a very basic structure: A `Category` can contain multiple items of `Product`:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category", cascade="remove")
 */
protected $products;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $category;
```

I get all products, when I access them through the *category* like this:

```php
$category->products;
```

Let's say a `Product` has an attribute `invisible`. How can I force Doctrine to only load the products that are **visible**. Where do I put this query? Into the *repository*? But than: How Do I call it or switch between "load all" and "load certain"? I could of course request the products separately, but this seems not like a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to simple add a visibility parameter to your category->getProducts() method:

```
class Category
{
public function getProducts($invisible = false)
{
    if ($invisible) return $this->products;

    $visibleProducts = array();
    foreach($this->products as $product)
    {
        if ($product->isVisible()) $visibleProducts[] = $product;
    }
    return $visibleProducts;
}
```

This does not prevent the loading of all products but it does give you an easy way to decide which products you want.  And it's very easy to implement.  You can refine it later.

A second approach would be to create a query to load all your categories with the products.  That will avoid the lazy loading of products and allow you to specify exactly which products you want.

And finally, you could follow @w1cked's suggestion and make a D2 filter.  Takes a little bit of effort to understand the process.

Comment: That's pretty nice and fast to implement. And I could store the already selected products in a class member so the loop would run only once.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion a better solution would be the usage of Doctrine Filters (if you are using Doctrine 2.2 or higher)

[Doctrine Filter manual](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html)

You can define a custom filter for you invisible property and enable/disable it whenever you want through the Entity Manager.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a "visibleProduct"-Entity, use Single-Table-Inheritance ( http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance ) and make a second relation from categories.